# Thunderbird / Firefox profile missing or inaccessible

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, profile, thunderbird

Suddenly, my Thunderbird and Firefox won't run because of this message:

```
Your Thunderbird profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

Even running `firefox/thunderbird --ProfileManager` ends with the same error

I'm on Arch Linux, latest packages. Tried also downgrading FF & TB - just in case. Apps stopped working after latest reboot (no system upgrade was done, just one app).

I can run TB and FF as root. My old profiles are commented out like `.mozilla_` and `.thunderbird_` so if I run FF it should create new `.mozilla` folder. Folder is successfully created but it is empty - no new profile folder nor `profiles.ini` file.

This is an example of freshly created .thunderbird directory in my Home

```
e@arch ~ $ l | grep thunderbird
drwx------  2 e    users     4096 Jan  2 22:17 .thunderbird
```

I tried to chmod `.thunderbird` to 777 with no luck. It looks to me like a permission problem. What should I look for? What is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so I found what was going on.. `.cache` directory in my `/home/e` was corrupted so I deleted it and voila.. all is going as it should. Sorry for bothering :)

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of hours, was going nuts from yesterday night! Thanks!